# Cannot access locals from +page.server.js

Tags: javascript, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, pocketbase

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doDKaKDvB30 on how to make a login/registration feature with sveltekit and pocketbase.

Here's what the hooks.server.js looks like:

```
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export const handle = async ({event, resolve}) => {
    event.locals.pb = new PocketBase('http://localhost:8090');
    event.locals.pb.authStore.loadFromCookie(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    
    if(event.locals.pb.authStore.isValid) {
        event.locals.user = event.locals.pb.authStore.model;
    }

    const response = await resolve(event);

    response.headers.set('set-cookie', event.locals.pb.authStore.exportToCookie({secure: false}));

    return response;
}
```

and the +page.server.js for the register screen:

```
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
    register: async ({ locals, request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
                const data = Object.fromEntries([...formData]);
        
                try {
            const newUser = await locals.pb.collection('users').create(data);

                    const {token, user} = await               
locals.pb.collection('users').authWithPassword(data.email, data.password);

        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
            return {
                error: true,
                message: err
            }
        }

                throw redirect(303, "/");
    
        },
};
```

But when I try to register a new user I get 2 errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
Data returned from action inside /register is not serializable: Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs (data..message)
```

I think that is because the data in locals is not being sent to +page.server.js, but I don't know why. That's how it is done in the tutorial and it works!

Comment: The second error is probably from the attempt to return `err` which usually is an `Error` instance, not a plain message; it cannot be serialized.

Comment: To add to @brunnerh's comment, you should probably be directly throwing the error or using the `error` helper from `@sveltejs/kit`. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. It was actually because my hooks was not in the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was a dumb mistake. My hooks.server.js was in /src/routes/ when it should have been in /src/.